# XCODE 4 Build Error

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xcode4, sencha-touch-2

I am new in iOS app development. I have created an app in Sencha Touch 2. Then created a `UIWebView` in xcode and follow this blog to call sencha's `index.html` to xcode's `UIWebView`.

> (Ref: http://www.innovaptor.com/blog/2013/05/06/create-a-sencha-touch-webapp-and-deploy-within-a-native-ios-app.html )

But when i am going to build the app, getting the following error.
[image]

Please help to solve this.
Thank You...

Comment: sei kalker error ta?